# Showing DF Times S-squared / sigma-squared is a chi-square

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-distribution, non-central

I am a beginning grad student (distance student, so nobody to ask in person), learning about distributions. I am trying to prove that $(n-1)s^2$ divided by $\sigma^2$ produces a non-central $\chi^2$ distribution. I do not understand how to do this. I am guessing I should use some properties of the the $\chi^2$ distribution to do this, but I don't know how.

Comment: What is your definition of the non-central $\chi^2$ distribution?  Exactly what is $s^2$?  (Your result is not always true; it depends on the context in which $s^2$ is computed and what assumptions you are making.)

Comment: I understand a $x^2$ distribution that is non-central is normally distributed with a mean $mu$and a variance of I with n degrees of freedom. I also know that I calculate non-centrality at $u^Tu$/2. $s^2$ are my errors, squared. 
I also am guessing that I should replace both $s^2$ and $sigma^2$ with something else. I just don't know what to do or how to prove this.

Comment: @whuber thanks! I edited and posted this as a new question because I am wanting to clarify the question, I want to somehow use the fact that $x^2$ has a quadratic form for it's non-centrality parameter

Comment: In the future, please just continue editing your question rather than posting a new version of it.